# train a model which is instantiated in another model ( Pytorch)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I have two classes of networks of neurons one of GNN type and the other simple of linear type, the latter is instantiated in the first !!! how can I train both at the same time?
here is an example:

```
class linear_NN(nn.Module):
  
  def __init__(self, input_dim, out_dim...):
    super().__init__()

  def forward(self, x, dim = 0):
    '''Forward pass'''
    return x
```

the main class or the large class

```
class GNN(nn.Module):
  
  def __init__(self, input_dim, n-hidden, out_dim...):
    super().__init__()

  def forward(self, h, dim = 0):
    '''Forward pass'''
    model=linear_NN(input, out..)
    model(h, dim)
    return h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare it in the `__init__(...)`:

```py
class GNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_dim, n-hidden, out_dim, ...):
    super().__init__()
    self.linear = linear_NN(input, out..)

  def forward(self, h, dim = 0):
    '''Forward pass'''
    self.linear(h, dim)
    return h
```

Then, the `self.linear` model will be registered to your `GNN` main model, and if you get `GNN(...).parameters()`, you'll see the linear parameters there.